# SQL: How to convert multiple date rows (Year, Jan, Feb, Mar,...,Dec) with values into column Date & value?

Tags: sql, date

I want to convert this:
[image]

into something like this:

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: UNION ALL, or UNPIVOT.

Comment: The expected VALUES column doesn't match any values in the existing table.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way would be something like:

```
select year || '-01' as time, jan as value from t union all
select year || '-02' as time, feb as value from t union all
. . .
```

That is, a `union all` that combines all the values.

That said, this would usually be more efficient as a lateral join (if the database supports that).  The syntax varies by database but is something like:

```
select t.year || '-' || v.suffix as time, v.value
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('01', t.jan), ('02', t.feb), . . .
     ) v(suffix, value)
```